# Hide item in div on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I turn off an item `data-toggle="select"` only on mobile devices? I found how to remove a class using Jquery. But how do you turn off the whole element in a div (I don't want to turn off the entire div, only part `data-toggle="select"`)?

```
<select name="type" data-toggle="select" id="id_type">
  [...]
</select>
```

Comment: Use CSS media query. On mobile device make item's ```display:none;```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you can use the `@media` queries to hide the element like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1080px) { // use any amount that you want
 select[data-toggle="select"] {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do I also need to add an attribute to the form class or just add it in the head section?

Comment: @MaddieGraham the query in my answer applies to  all `<select>` elements with the `data-toggle` attribute set to `select`, e.g.: `<select data-toggle="select"> [...] </select>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `test(navigator.userAgent)` can help you.

```js
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent); //Check if it's running on a mobile device
var element = document.getElementById('text');
if (isMobile) {
 document.getElementById("id_type").setAttribute("data-toggle", "");
} else {
 document.getElementById("id_type").setAttribute("data-toggle", "select");
}
```